# Mongoose Required true and Enum validation not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

Mongoose Required true and Enum validation not working while using updateone

```
await MonthlyTarget.updateOne({website: req.body.website, year: req.body.year, month: req.body.month}, req.body, {upsert: true});
```

Model

```
'use strict';
import pkg from 'mongoose';
const { Schema, model } = pkg;

const monthlyTargetSchema = new Schema({
    website: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Websites', index: true, required: true },
    category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'IncidentCategory', index: true, required: true },
    year: { type: String, index: true },
    month: { type: String, required: true, enum:['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june', 'july', 'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december'], index: true },
    target: { type: Schema.Types.Number, index: true },
});

const MonthlyTarget = model('MonthlyTarget', monthlyTargetSchema);
export default MonthlyTarget;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Agreed with the bot, I could help but I don't really understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`const updatedUser = await User.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id},{ $set: data },{ runValidators: true });`